# The operator induced by $T$ on quotient space $\frac{V}{kerT}$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

A linear operator $T$  on a complex vector space $V$ has characteristic polynomial $x^3(x-5)^2$ and minimal polynomial $x^2(x-5)$. Then prove or disprove the following.

The operator induced by $T$ on quotient space $\frac{V}{kerT}$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

My attempt:
Here $dim(ker T) =1$

$T:V\to V$ and $T:\frac{V}{kerT} \to \frac{V}{kerT}$

From given information, we get $$T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you know what the induced operator on the quotient is?

Comment: I don't know about it. Please help me

Comment: Do you know what a quotient space is? If $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, do you know what $V/W$ (also denoted $\frac VW$) is?

Comment: Yes,  If $v \in V$ then $v+W \in V/W$

Comment: Right. Make sure you're comfortable with the following basic facts: (1) If $x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n$ is a basis for $V$ such that $x_1,\dots,x_k$ is basis for $W$, then $x_{k+1}+W,\dots,x_n+W$ is a basis for $V/W$. (2) If $T : V \to V$ is a linear operator, and $T(W) \subseteq W$, then we can define a linear operator $T/W : V/W \to V/W$ via $(T/W)(v+W) := T(v)+W$, the so-called **induced operator by $T$ on $V/W$**.

Comment: (3) If $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n$, $B$ is the matrix representation of the restriction of $T$ on $W$ with respect to the basis $x_1,\dots,x_k$, and $C$ is the matrix representation of $T/W$ with respect to the basis $x_{k+1}+W,\dots,x_n+W$, then $$A = \begin{pmatrix} B & * \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Here $|A| = |B| |C|$. What about $|A|$ and $|B|$ ?

Comment: Determinants are not helpful here. If $V = \mathbb C^5$, $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$ is the standard basis, and $T$ is the linear operator such that $Te_1 = 0$, $Te_2 = e_1$, $Te_3 = e_2$, $Te_4 = 5e_4$ and $Te_5 = 5e_5$, observe that $e_1$ is a basis for $W = \ker T$. What is the matrix representation of $T/W$ with respect to the basis $e_2+W,e_3+W,e_4+W,e_5+W$?

Comment: Your hints are sufficient to approach the answer. I think that I have less knowledge. Let $B$ is a matrix of $T/Ker T$. Then $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} $. I know that this site helps partially when there is a difficult and it is a not a question and answer machine. I'm humble requesting to you to provide a solution by combining above hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, then the following facts are well-known:

- Given a linear operator $T : V \to V$, if $T(W) \subseteq W$ (that is, for every $w \in W$ one has $T(w) \in W$) then we can define two new linear operators:

  - $T_W : W \to W$ that sends $w \in W$ to $T(w)$, in symbols, $T_W(w) := T(w)$.
  - $T/W : V/W \to V/W$ that sends $v + W \in V/W$ to $T(v)+W$, in symbols, $(T/W)(v+W) := T(v)+W.$
- When $V$ is finite-dimensional, say $\dim V = n$ and $\dim W = k$, if $x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n$ is a basis for $V$ such that $x_1,\dots,x_k$ is a basis for $W$, then $x_{k+1}+W,\dots,x_n+W$ is a basis for $V/W$ (so that $\dim(V/W) = n-k$).
- Continuing with the previous points, the matrix that represents $T$ in the basis $x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n$ looks like $$\begin{pmatrix} B & E \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}$$ where $B$ is the $k \times k$ matrix that represents $T_W$ in the basis $x_1,\dots,x_k$; $C$ is the $(n-k) \times (n-k)$ matrix that represents $T/W$ in the basis $x_{k+1}+W,\dots,x_n+W$; and $E$ is some $k \times (n-k)$ matrix. (Obviously, "$0$" is the $(n-k) \times k$ zero matrix).

---

Now, if $V = \mathbb C^5$, consider the linear operator $T : V \to V$ such that $$T(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5) = (z_2,z_3,0,5z_4,5z_5), \qquad z_i \in \mathbb C.$$
Thus, if $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$ is the standard basis for $V$, then we see that $e_1$ is a basis for $W = \ker T$, and since $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
is the matrix that represents $T$ in the basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$, in this case
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$
is the matrix that represents $T/W$ in the basis $e_2+W,e_3+W,e_4+W,e_5+W$. In particular, $T/W$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity map.

Comment: I must say that the answer is really informative and beautiful. However I am stuck on how did you arrive at  the last matrix. We have $T/W(e_2+W)=T(e_2)+W=T(0,1,0,0,0)+W=(1,0,0,0,0)+W$. How did you get the matrix representation of $T/W$ as $\begin{bmatrix} 0,1,0,0\\0,0,0,0\\0,0,5,0\\0,0,0,5\end{bmatrix}$? Will you please explain a bit ?

Comment: @Olivia Sure. Note that $e_1 \in W$, so $e_1+W = 0+W$. I didn't make any calculations, I just used the third bullet of my "basic facts".

Comment: @azif00, I made a mistake in minimal polynomial, there should be $x^2(x-5)$ instead of $x^3(x-5)$. I edited. Please edit the answer if required.

Comment: The old version of the problem might be helpful to someone in the future. This new (version of the) question should be in a new post.